# How to implement 'set -o pipefail' in a POSIX way - almost done, expert help needed

Tags: shell, command-line, pipe, posix

I have to implement the BASH `set -o pipefail` option in a POSIX way so that it works on various LINUX/UNIX flavors. To explain a bit, this option enables the user to verify the successful execution of all piped commands. With this option enabled this command `cat app.log | grep 'ERROR'` fails if `cat` fails, otherwise the `cat` error is suppressed.

So, I found a really nice solution here: http://cfaj.ca/shell/cus-faq-2.html

```
      run() {
         j=1
         while eval "\${pipestatus_$j+:} false"; do
           unset pipestatus_$j
           j=$(($j+1))
         done
         j=1 com= k=1 l=
         for a; do
           if [ "x$a" = 'x|' ]; then
             com="$com { $l "'3>&-
                         echo "pipestatus_'$j'=$?" >&3
                       } 4>&- |'
             j=$(($j+1)) l=
           else
             l="$l \"\$$k\""
           fi
           k=$(($k+1))
         done
         com="$com $l"' 3>&- >&4 4>&-
                    echo "pipestatus_'$j'=$?"'
         exec 4>&1
         eval "$(exec 3>&1; eval "$com")"
         exec 4>&-
         j=1
         while eval "\${pipestatus_$j+:} false"; do
           eval "[ \$pipestatus_$j -eq 0 ]" || return 1
           j=$(($j+1))
         done
         return 0
       }
```

The above-mentioned `run()` function enables the user to invoke the piped commands in such a way:

```
run cmd1 \| cmd2 \| cmd3
```

If one of the commands fails you get it in `$?`

There is a problem however, it does not support the grouping of commands between pipes. I want to be able to invoke something like this:

```
run echo "test" ; grep "test" \| awk '{print}'
```

When I do it, the invocation fails. I cannot get the right modification to support the grouping of commands -- the script is a bit too complex for my bash skills...

Could somebody help?

Thanks!

Comment: `;` does not group commands between pipes in bash. `( ... ; ... )` or `{ ... ; ... ; }` does.

Comment: `set -o pipefail`. `set -e` is different. This is possible but probably more effort than its worth. Ksh also supports pipefail, and mksh supports `PIPESTATUS` which can easily be used to implement pipefail. I would seriously consider using a different language before attempting this in POSIX sh.

Comment: @choroba - this is what I meant. You are right. This does not work either.

Comment: @ormaaj I need a consistent and single way to handle this. The run() method is fine, so I don't think it's a lot of effort to add the grouping.

Answer (score 13):

My two cents:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Saving the pid of the main shell is required,
# as each element of the pipe is a subshell.
self=$$

lots_and_fail() {
    seq 100
    return 1
}

{ lots_and_fail || kill $self; } | sed s/7/3/
```

This thing seems to do the job.  Thoughts?

Comment: So let me get this straight. You downvoted the answer because it contains an obviously rhetorical question, or do you actually see a reason why this solution is not good?  Would you mind to elaborate on your downvote?

Comment: Clever. But why doesn't it work if instead of `kill` you use `exit 1`?

Comment: @jimis - exit 1 exits the subshell :)

Comment: If wrap guts into function it would be a bit nicer: 
`try() { set -e ; trap 'kill $$' EXIT ; eval "$@" ; }`. And use it as `try cmd1 | ... cmdN`

Comment: @jsxt: nice to see, could it be that the last sentence of [Jonathan Leffler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13087710/367456) may also apply to this?: _"It assumes that wrapping double quotes around an argument neutralizes it correctly, which is not always true (though it is true a lot of the time)."_ [referring originally to OP]. Or does `eval "$@"` make this fully transparent?

Comment: @hakre, surely. My suggestion just accumulates the best stuff of the suggestions by Dacav and Jonathan Leffler.

Answer (score 6):

When you type:

```
run echo "test" ; grep "test" \| awk '{print}'
```

you invoke `run` with the arguments `echo` and `"test"`; then you invoke `grep` with arguments `"test"`, `|`, `awk` and `{print}`.  Typically, `grep` is not going to find any of the files called `|`, `awk` or `{print}`.

To invoke `run` as you wanted, you'd have to escape the semi-colon like you did the `|` (and you'd need to do things similarly for `&&` or `||` or `&` and possibly other components of a command line; the handling of `$(...)` or backticks `` `...` `` needs to be thought about carefully).

If you write:

```
run echo "test" \; grep "test" \| awk '{print}'
```

you will at least get all the arguments you intended to `run`.  Whether it then works is debatable; I don't yet understand how the `run` code you showed is supposed to work.

*[...Later...]*

It does some fearsome I/O redirections, but wraps each segment of a command separated by a pipe symbol into a separate little packet of hieroglyphs.  It assumes that wrapping double quotes around an argument neutralizes it correctly, which is not always true (though it is true a lot of the time).

Answer (score 1):

The core of your idea should probably involve something like this:

```
{ cmd1 ; echo $? > status1 ; } | cmd2 && grep -q '^0$' status1 }
```

In longer form, that would be:

```
{ cmd1 ; echo $? > status1 ; } |  \
{ cmd2 ; echo $? > status2 ; } |  \
  # ... and so on                 \
  cmdN                         && \
  # ^ note lack of wrapper        \ 
grep -q '^0$' status1 &&          \
grep -q '^0$' status2 &&          \
  # ... and so on, to N-1
```