# How to cause a Linux pipeline to fail?

Tags: shell, pipe, posix, pipeline

Recently I'm learning the `set -e` of POSIX shell on Ubuntu 14.04. My reference material is the "IEEE Std 1003.1-2008, 2016 Edition", "Shell & Utilities" chapter. From [this section](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set) I see `-e` doesn't cause the script to quit when the command fails in a pipeline (unless the failed command is the last one in the pipeline):

> The failure of any individual command in a multi-command pipeline shall not cause the shell to exit. Only the failure of the pipeline itself shall be considered.

I then wrote a simple script to confirm this behavior:

```
(
    set -e
    false | true | false | true
    echo ">> Multi-command pipeline: Last command succeeded."
)
(
    set -e
    false | true | false
    echo ">> Multi-command pipeline: Last command failed."
)
```

The "Last command succeeded" message is printed out, while the "Last command failed" message is not.

My questions are:

- The chained commands `false | true | false` don't seem to be a failure of the pipeline. It's just the failure of the last command. **The pipeline itself still succeeds. Am I right??**
- **Is there a way to simulate a pipeline failure??** We can use `false` to simulate the failure of a command. Is there a similar command for a pipeline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default in bash, the success or failure of a pipeline is determined solely by the last command in the pipeline.

You may however enable the `pipefail` option (`set -o pipefail`) and the pipeline will return failure if any command in the pipeline fails.

#### Example

This pipeline succeeds:

```
$ false | true | false | true ; echo $?
0
```

This pipeline fails:

```
$ set -o pipefail
$ false | true | false | true ; echo $?
1
```

#### Documentation

From `man bash`:

> The  return  status of a pipeline is the exit status of the last
>   command, unless  the pipefail option is enabled.  If pipefail is
>   enabled, the  pipeline's  return       status is the value of the last
>   (rightmost) command to exit with a non-zero status, or zero if all
>   commands exit successfully.

Answer (score 1):

> The chained commands `false | true | false` don't seem to be a failure of the pipeline. It's just the failure of the last command. The pipeline itself still succeeds. Am I right?

The success of a pipeline is specified to be the success of the last command. They are the same thing.

From [§2.9.2 Pipelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_02):

> If the pipeline does not begin with the `!` reserved word, **the exit status shall be the exit status of the last command specified in the pipeline**. Otherwise, the exit status shall be the logical NOT of the exit status of the last command. That is, if the last command returns zero, the exit status shall be 1; if the last command returns greater than zero, the exit status shall be zero.

In bash and ksh this you can use `set -o pipefail` to cause the pipeline to fail if any command in it fails. This is [not a POSIX option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13084352/how-to-implement-set-o-pipefail-in-a-posix-way-almost-done-expert-help-nee), unfortunately. It ought to be, but it isn't.